# Python function/lists

Tags: python, list, function

how do i create a function that adds something to an empty list, but if the value already exists on that list it cant be added, and has to go to another empty list. I tried this but this doesn't takes into account if a value other than x is already on the list

```
List = []
leftover = []
x = 2

def add(x):
    if myUniqueList[0:] == []:
        myUniqueList.append(x)
        print("True")
        print(myUniqueList)
    elif myUniqueList[0:] == [x]:
        leftover.append(x)
        print("False")
        print(leftover)

add(x)
```

Comment: Read about operator `in` and how to use it to check if `x` is already in the list.

Comment: what is `myUniqueList`? Also it is better to follow PEP-8 and use underscore_seperated_names for variables and not CamelCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work. By using the `if x not in` syntax, we can easily check to see if the number is in the existing list.
If it is not in the list, we then append it. If it is in the list, we append it to the leftover list.

```
mylist = []                                                                                                                                                           
leftover = []
x = 2    

def add(x): 
    if x not in mylist: 
        mylist.append(x) 
        print('True') 
        print(mylist) 
    else: 
        leftover.append(x) 
        print('False') 
        print(leftover)                           

add(x)
```

## Set vs List:

There are some performance ramifications if you are using massive sequences of numbers. In which case, storing the numbers in a Python `set()` will greatly speed up any lookups to see if the number already exists. This is due to the way that Python stores numbers in `sets` vs `lists`.

```
myset = set()                                                                                                                                                   
leftover = []
x = 2    

def add(x): 
    if x not in mylist: 
        mylist.add(x)      # sets use .add() instead of .append() 
        print('True') 
        print(myset)       
        print(list(myset)) # IF you need to print out a list, you can 
                           # convert sets to lists by encapsulating 
                           # the myset with the list() factory function
                           # BUT if you do this every cycle you prolly
                           # start to lose the performance benefits.
    else: 
        leftover.append(x) 
        print('False') 
        print(leftover)                           

add(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List = []
leftover = []
x = 2

def add(x):
    if x in myUniqueList:
        print("False")
        print(leftover)
        leftover.append(x)
    else:
        myUniqueList.append(x)
        print("True")
        print(myUniqueList)

add(x)
```